# Reading all sections in a config file

Tags: python, python-2.7

My idea is to fetch all the component versions installed in all the different labs across the world. My code works when i give the details explicitly.

My code is as follows

```
def UK_PDL_HE():
    UK_PDL_List = {}
    sorted_list = {}
    slist = {}
    HE_string = "UK_PDL_HE"
    global config
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    print config.sections()
    config.read('config.cfg')
    env.user = config.get('UK_PDL','db.user_name' )
    env.password = config.get('UK_PDL','db.password' )
    host = config.get('UK_PDL','db.ip' )
    with settings(hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'), warn_only=True, host_string=host):
    paramiko.util.log_to_file('UK_PDL.log')
    files = run('ls -ltr /opt/nds')
    with open("UK_PDL.txt", "w") as fo:
        fo.write(files)
    components = []
    with open("UK_PDL.txt", 'rb') as fo:
        strings = ("/installed/")
        i=0
        for line in fo:
            if strings in line:
                id = re.search('installed/(.+)',line)
                if id:
                components.append(id.group(1))
                component,version = components[i].rstrip().split('-',1)
                UK_PDL_List[component] = version
                i+=1
        write_data(UK_PDL_List, HE_string,1)
```

The config file is as follows

```
[UK_PDL]
db.user_name = user
db.password = password
db.ip = 101.815.117.193

[UK_DTH]
db.user_name = user
db.password = password
db.ip = 272.119.411.121
```

Currently i have written functions for each IP. Instead of this how can i make sure that all the entries are read from the config one by one and fetch the details?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking... you just want to loop over the sections of a config file without knowing the section names?

Comment: Yes. Instead of giving the names, i need to give numerals 1, 2 etc in the config [replacing UK_PDL & UK_DTH]. If i have 10 sections, one function should search for all the 10 sections in the config and output the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop over the sections and build file names dynamically:

```
def any_HE():
    global config
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('config.cfg')
    for section in config.sections():
        list = {} #start with empty list for each section
        env.user = config.get(section, 'db.user_name')
        env.password = config.get(section, 'db.password')
        host = config.get(section, 'db.ip')
        with settings(hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'), \
                        warn_only=True, host_string=host):
            paramiko.util.log_to_file(section + '.log')
            files = run('ls -ltr /opt/nds')
            with open(section + ".txt", "w") as fo:
                fo.write(files)
            components = []
            with open(section + ".txt", 'rb') as fo:
                strings = ("/installed/")
                i=0
                for line in fo:
                    if strings in line:
                        id = re.search('installed/(.+)',line)
                        if id:
                            components.append(id.group(1))
                            component,version = components[i].rstrip().split('-',1)
                            list[component] = version
                            i+=1
            write_data(list, section + "_HE", 1)
```

The indenting of your code seemed to be wrong at some places, so I had to make some assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

To loop over the sections in a config file:

```
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.cfg')
for section in config.sections():
    print(section, dict(config[section]))
```

To access the `n`th section:

```
config[config.sections()[n]]
```

Comment: I am getting an error when i use the same section as mentioned above. 
config = ConfigParser()   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @Roshanr `ConfigParser` here refers to the class, not the module. Try `ConfigParser.ConfigParser()`

Comment: I tried this       config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        for section in config.sections():
        print(section, dict(config[section]))  but got /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/roradhak/Work/Scripts/ComponentListing/build/lib/SSHCOnnect.py

Process finished with exit code 0 as output